# Using subject and observable as I/O service parameters to avoid dependence on http request/reponse structure and the service providing http calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am building a service, which needs to open a modal, and trigger a chain of http calls on certain user interactions. The APIs i need to call depend on the actual context where the service is being used, as well as the API parameters.
I wanted to avoid having to define callbacks to use my service, or using the httpService (or its wrapped version) as parameter as then it would have to implement certain methods my service expects - to keep usage as simple as possible. Also avoiding callbacks was an external expectation.

I'm still learning rxjs, and not sure if this is an acceptable solution using a subject like this, or are there better ways?

Is it safe from memory leaks to use Subject this way?

I assumed using takeUntil and calling next on destroy$ will cancel any subscription on my end, and everything will be garbage collected when the modal opened by the service and the parent component is both destroyed.
Ideally only one modal component will be active at a time, but i don't know if there won't be several instances existing in browser memory at any given time so i'm not sure if exposing a single/global Subject property in the service would be a good idea.

```
export class myService {
  doStuff(
    subject: Subject<InputType>,
    mappedSubject: Observable<ResponseType1>,
    otherAPICall: Observable<ResponseType2>,
  ) {
    return this.dialog.open({data: { subject, mappedSubject, otherAPICall });
  }
}
```

in the modal:

```
private destroy$ = new Subject();

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.data.mappedSubject.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    flatMap(result => {
      if (result.allGood) return this.data.otherAPICall;
       Observable.throw("not good");
    }),
  ).subscribe(result => displayResult(result));
}

doOnButtonClick() {
  this.data.subject.next(this.form.get("myInput").value);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

usage in another component:

```
const subject = new Subject()<InputType>;
this.myService.doStuff(
  subject,
  subject.pipe(
    flatMap(inputValue => this.httpService1.call(this.transform(inputValue))),
    map(x => (x as ResponseType1)),
  ),
  this.httpService2.call(params).pipe(map(x => (x as ResponseType2)),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only concern is, why are we passing Subject as data property inside open(). Using DI you can inject service anywhere in Component/Service constructor and access it there right?.

Avoid passing subject, this may lead to memory consumption and performance issues.

Instead of using 'flatMap', you can try switchMap. This will cancel previous the source observable Http call if active.

Comment: There are a lot of services which have to provide input for this service depending on where this service is being used. Injecting all of them is not an option.

Comment: If you don't want to inject inside constructor. using Injector Class, you can access any provider using injector.get().

Comment: The problem isn't the way how i access those services from this service.
It is not known what service will provide the API calls for this service in advance.